# Add "Find File" button to setting of type string array

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

For my extension in VSCode I would like to add a number of paths to a classpath for a jar that is executed in the extension. For this, I have added a configuration setting with the type string array. In VSCode this is rendered in the settings UI with an "Add item" button, which allows the user to add a line to the array.

Since all the lines should be paths, I would like to add a button next to it like "Find" which opens a search window (like the one for "File">"Open Folder...").

So the question is, is it possible to add a custom button to the string array rendering?

The configuration currently looks something like:

```
"extension.classPathAdditions": {
          "type": "array",
          "items": {"type":"string"},
          "default": [],
          "scope": "resource",
          "markdownDescription": "List of folder and/or file paths that should be included in the class path for the language server.  [Find files](command:extension.addFilesToClassPath) or add manually."
        },
```

Alternatively, is it possible in the extension to determine which settings scope the user is looking at? I.e., is the user looking at User, Workspace, or some Folder settings?

Comment: You can't modify the Settings GUI, There is no hook in the Settings page to get notified of a tab change

Comment: Bummer, thanks though!